# Mapbox Heatmap with gl js API, how to change background or overlay color to be less dark?

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, heatmap, mapbox-gl-js

I am using this tutorial to make a heatmap.

[Mapbox Heatmap Tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/make-a-heatmap-with-mapbox-gl-js/)

I have barely changed the display settings from how it is displayed here.

I am hoping to make the overlay less dark so that smaller towns and street names show up more clearly. Or possibly even do a heatmap over the satelite or streetview.

More simply how do I style the overlay or background to be a different color or lighter?

And if I wanted to how would I do a heatmap over a satellite or streetview layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by changing the source style to something else Like:

```
                 style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v12',
```